# How to export to a text file from powershell and run it in our computer?

Tags: powershell, export-to-excel

I am new to powershell and learning some important things.
When I executed the command `Get-Process` and `Get-HotFix`, I got the output with all the udpates in the system.  How can I export those to a text file which can be edited ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to become proficient in using the Powershell [pipeline](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/06/30/back-to-the-basics-part-1-learning-about-the-powershell-pipeline.aspx) so that you can 'pipe' the results of the commands you execute into the [Out-File](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee176924.aspx) cmdlet.  In particular, look to pipe the [output to a CSV file](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/02/04/use-powershell-to-create-csv-file-to-open-in-excel.aspx) that can be input into Excel.

Comment: Thanks I will go through this

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect command output to files using the right angle bracket, `>`.

`Get-Process > c:\foo.txt`

If you want to process the results some first, you can use `echo`.

```
$procs = Get-Process
$smallProcs = $procs | Where-Object { $_.Id -lt 1000 }
$smallProcs | echo > c:\foo.txt
```

Another useful one is the one used to append, the double right angle bracket: `>>`. It works the same as the single output redirect `>`, except it will leave existing file contents there and append the new content to the end.

Comment: I will try out this method also